# Kubuntu 9.04 - Can't drag application from one screen to another in multi monitor setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, kubuntu

I have a new install of Kubuntu 9.04. I installed the ati drivers.

```
fglrxinfo
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI FirePro V3750 (FireGL)
OpenGL version string: 2.1.8794 FireGL
```

When dragging a window from one monitor to the second monitor it stops when the mouse hits the edge of the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: What settings are you using?  In particular, is your second monitor set to "TwinView" or "Separate X Display"?  How are you configuring the two monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you can't drag windows from one 'head' onto another 'head' is (as 
CarlF correctly commented) that your setup is in "separate x display" mode and not in "xinerama mode" (aka "twinview in nvidia-land or "bigdesktop").

such a "separate x display" setup means, that each head can possibly run a completely different configuration regarding visual depth, size, framerate etc. thus, a window created on one head (the term is actually "screen") can not be savely moved onto the other head because the "pixels do not match".

checkout 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=221174 and configure your xserver correctly, then your problems will vanish .)

Comment: I finally got it working with the help of this blog post http://sensiblerationalization.blogspot.com/2009/06/dual-monitor-setup-with-fedora-10-and.html

Comment: Ah, great answer I wish I could upvote twice