# Maximize windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ati-mobility-radeon

I have a dual-screen setup, and I would like to configure it so that when I maximize a program, it only maximize on one screen instead of both.

I have ubuntu 9.04 aka Jaunty Jackalope, amd64 architecture if it matters, and a ATI Mobility Radeon 3650.

edit:
I forgot to mention that my window manager is gnome.

Comment: what is your desktop environment/window manager?

Comment: the answer will finally result in 'setup your xserver to use xinerama / twinview / bigdesktop', but lets wait what he says about his wm

Comment: @akira, is not twinView specfic to nvidia cards only?

Comment: twinview is nvidia-specific, but there are other ways of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: @elhoim - thats why i said: xinerama / twinview / bigdesktop. in that order. twinview and bigdesktop are just variants of xinerama.

Comment: @akira How am i supposed to configure xinerama then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i would go the route the superuser [51233](https://superuser.com/questions/51233/kubuntu-9-04-cant-drag-application-from-one-screen-to-another-in-multi-monitor/51293#51293) took; he had a 'different' problem but the reson was the same: how to setup xinerama. once your xinerama is running, your windowmanager should do "the right thing"(tm) when it comes to maximizing a window.

if not: change to fluxbox (i am a bit biased here :)).

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial helped me:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo#ATI

It even gives a xorg.conf that works as is for me.

Comment: Even more details: http://sernaonubuntu.wikidot.com/multiple-monitors